# Tabbar is not showing in React Navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, screen

I'm using react-navigation to create a tabbar. So here is the code of the tabbar I've created:

```
const Tabbar = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNav.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
            let iconName;     

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? <HomeBold />
                : <Home />
            } else if (route.name === 'Music') {
              iconName = focused
                ? <SoundBold />
                : <Sound />
            } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
              iconName = focused
                ? <PersonalRoomBold />
                : <PersonalRoom />
            }

            return <Image name={iconName} />;
          },
        })}      
      >      
        <TabNav.Screen 
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <TabNav.Screen 
          name="Music"
          component={MusicScreen}
        />
        <TabNav.Screen 
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
        />
      </TabNav.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I'm expecting to get something like this:

[image]

But getting just nothing. How can I fix that?

Comment: So it just doesn’t render anything on screen? Or the result is not as you expect

Comment: If you are talking about icons the not showing, that would make sense because you're returning an `Image` component with a `name` prop with a component as a value. I'm guessing you want to use vector icons instead of images like this: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#basic-example. The bar itself should show up fine.

Comment: So I should just use Icon component from react-native-vector-icons instead of an Image, right?

Comment: Yes and the name prop of the `Icon` takes a string. You can find all list of icons with corresponding names for different icon sets here: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/.

Comment: Thanks for help dude

Comment: @BasvanderLinden So, I've succesfully installed react-native-vector-icons. I wanna use my own, so I created a config and font with help of fontello. But I still don't see my Icons. How is it possible?